# Connection Failed when Deploying with Capistrano in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a PHP project using Capistrano. When I try to do a `cap deploy`, I get an error:

```
wes:/var/www/nipponpulse [svn:] → cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "svn info https://newcitymedia.svn.beanstalkapp.com/nippon_pulse/expressionengine  -rHEAD"
/opt/local/bin/svn
  * executing "svn checkout -q  -r94 https://newcitymedia.svn.beanstalkapp.com/nippon_pulse/expressionengine /var/www/nipponpulse/releases/20091117150904 && (echo 94 > /var/www/nipponpulse/releases/20091117150904/REVISION)"
    servers: ["192.168.2.42"]
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/nipponpulse/releases/20091117150904; true"
    servers: ["192.168.2.42"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError,      connection failed for: 192.168.2.42 (NoMethodError: private method `split' called for 42:Fixnum)
    connection failed for: 192.168.2.42 (NoMethodError: private method `split' called for 42:Fixnum)
```

Here's the recipe I'm using http://pastie.textmate.org/private/7mix7xhbf3ozwjskwt5orq. I'm using Snow Leopard and here's my list of gems (using `sudo gem list --local`):

```
actionmailer (2.3.4, 2.2.2, 1.3.6)
actionpack (2.3.4, 2.2.2, 1.13.6)
actionwebservice (1.2.6)
activerecord (2.3.4, 2.2.2, 1.15.6)
activeresource (2.3.4, 2.2.2)
activesupport (2.3.4, 2.2.2, 1.4.4)
acts_as_ferret (0.4.4, 0.4.3)
adamcooke-key-installer (1.1)
capistrano (2.5.9, 2.5.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.0.10)
defunkt-github (0.3.4)
dnssd (1.3.1, 1.3, 0.6.0)
fastthread (1.0.7, 1.0.1)
fcgi (0.8.7)
ferret (0.11.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
highline (1.5.1, 1.5.0)
hpricot (0.8.1, 0.6.164)
json_pure (1.1.9)
libxml-ruby (1.1.3, 1.1.2)
mongrel (1.1.5)
needle (1.3.0)
net-scp (1.0.2, 1.0.1)
net-sftp (2.0.2, 2.0.1, 1.1.1)
net-ssh (2.0.15, 2.0.4, 1.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
open4 (0.9.6)
rack (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
rails (2.3.4, 2.2.2, 1.2.6)
rake (0.8.7, 0.8.3)
RedCloth (4.2.2, 4.1.1)
ruby-openid (2.1.7, 2.1.2)
ruby-yadis (0.3.4)
rubygems-update (1.3.5)
rubynode (0.1.5)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5, 1.2.4)
termios (0.9.4)
vlad (2.0.0)
xmpp4r (0.5, 0.4)
```

When I run `ruby -v` I see this:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

I'm not sure why it's failing. My experience with rails and ruby in general is slim to none, but I've used Capistrano in the past and it has worked on this machine. Is there something specific with Snow Leopard that I need to fix?

**Edit:** updated the error

Answer (score 0):

Note that the error reads "exception while rolling back", which means that the error you're seeing occurred when Capistrano was already trying to rollback due to some other error. In other words, it's a red herring. If you can include the complete output of capistrano from the command in question, someone might be able to help you identify what really went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should examine this error:

connection failed for: 192.168.2.42 (NoMethodError: private method `split' called for 42:Fixnum)

What host is this? Local? And try to check where the NoMethodError for split comes from.

You can also fire this cap command just to see if the destination server is the one not reachable:

```
cap invoke COMMAND='ls -l'
```